# How can I enable CORS in Apache2 and Xampp

Tags: javascript, json, apache, google-maps-api-3, xampp

I'm using google maps JS api and I'm going to import JSON into the html file.
The documentation indicates that CORS must be enabled on the server.

I use Xampp and Apache2, I added the code to httpd.config file as what the tutorial said, but it still doesn't work

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

the error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/googlemap/google.json. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Looks like you're viewing the HTML via local file instead of through the web server. Try accessing your site from localhost.